# cypress Component Testing missing webpack, but is detected

Tags: reactjs, webpack, configuration, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I would like to configure component testing in Component Testing.

```
Frontend framework: React.js(detected); Bundler (Dev Server): Webpack(detected)

Next Step: all ok. webpack >=4.0.0; react >=16.x
```

Continue: I can see short the cypress.config.js in green and than:

```
Error:
You are using webpack for your dev server, but a configuration file was not found. 
We traversed upwards from:
/home/projekte/bitbucket/teeth/cypress
looking for a file named:
webpack.config.ts
webpack.config.js
webpack.config.mjs
webpack.config.cjs
Add your webpack config at one of the above paths, or import your configuration file
and provide it to the devServer config as a webpackConfig option.
```

I have in /home/projekte/bitbucket/teeth/frontend/node_modules a webpack directory.
I can import the webpack.config.js in my cypress directory and this issue is not more present. But I think it is not so simple. What can I do for a correct using?

The frontend, backend and cypress are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add a webpack.config.js file to you file directory to resolve the issue